# Why the timer class i added to my project the timer doesn't start when i click the button?

Tags: java, android

In my project in MainActivity.java i have:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
        "http://192.168.1.10:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
    private TextView text;
    private boolean connectedtoipsuccess = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private TextView text1, text2, text3;
    private long starttime = 0;

    private TimerCounter tc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tc = new TimerCounter();
    }
}
```

In the TimerCounter class i have:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;

    public class TimerCounter extends Activity
    {
        private Button startButton;
        private Button pauseButton;

        private TextView timerValue;

        private long startTime = 0L;

        private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

        long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
        long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
        long updatedTime = 0L;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

            startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

            startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

                }
            });

            pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

            pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

                }
            });

        }

        private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

                updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }

        };
    }
```

This is the xml file code of the resources buttons and textviews:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="WEBSERVER"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="HttpURLConnection\nIP Based" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checking Connection.."
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Ip"
        android:id="@+id/checkipbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:text="startButtonLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pauseButtonLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The bottom TextView and two BUTTONS are for using the TimerCounter.

Then i have the file strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">WebServerTest</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string       name="title_activity_activity_motion_event">activity_motion_event</string>
    <string name="status1_string">Touch One Status</string>
    <string name="title_activity_activity__motion">Activity_Motion</string>
    <string name="status_string">Touch One Status</string>
    <string name="timerVal">00:00:00</string>
    <string name="pauseButtonLabel">Pause</string>
    <string name="startButtonLabel">Start</string>
</resources>
```

I'm not getting any erorrs or exceptions but when i'm running my program and click the Start Button nothing happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different reasons that explain why your application does not behave as expected.

First, your TimerCounter class extends Activity. When you call  tc = new TimerCounter(), you are probably trying to launch the TimerCounter activity. If you want to achieve that, you have to use an Android Intent and launch it

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TimerCounter.class);
startActivity(i);
```

You should also declare your Activity in your manifest.xml :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.webservertest.TimerCounter"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         />
```

You where probably fooled by the fact that your two activities have the same layout (R.layout.activity_main). So when you click on the button, you are still in your MainActivity, not in TimerCounter Activity.

Then, to optimize your Timer, you may use a TimerTask associated with a Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
tc = new TimerCounter();
```

with these lines:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TimerCounter.class);
startActivity(i);
```

It also seems a bit strange that both of your activities are using the same resource file. Could you just use one activity, since all your **MainActivity** does is send you to the **TimerCounter** activity?